# Google spreadsheet conditional formatting to verify if 2 cells are equal

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Using Google spreadsheets,

I am looking forward to compare a testing and validation set from a sentiment analysis model where I get 3 different tags: Disagreement, Agreement and Neutral for data curation,

The example table is the following:

```
positivity_ratio    sentiment       Test
0.51                Neutral         Disagreement
0.15                Disagreement    Disagreement
0.04                Disagreement    Disagreement
0                   Disagreement    Disagreement
0                   Disagreement    Disagreement
```

What I like to achieve is the following: To highlight both cells when the values are equal (sentiment = Test) in one color and use another color to highlight when the value in columns do not match (sentiment != Test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way I find to do it is to select your whole column sentiment then go to format put the personalized formula : =B1=C1 and this will color all sentiment which have the same sentiment and Test. If you want to have both sentiment and Test colored you will have to select the whole column Test and put the same formula =B1=C1.
If you did it, now you ll be able to see all the items that have both sentiment and test with the same color. If you wanna put the other one (the ones which are different) in an other color then you can just put the "not empty" statement and choose the color.
Ask me if it wasn't clear enough.